google-smart-home ewelink sonoff trvzb cinteol
I have a sonoff advanced gateway and trvzb set-up. eWelink set-up and linked with Google home. As member of beta, I have the scripting in running. Here is the glitch: I expect to use the state heating / not heating to switch an device toSwitch.
However the state Auto/on or off/frost protection is in the script available.
Question now: how do I use in stead the syntax If exampleTRVZB is below setpoint, heating is true. Or if thermostatTemperatureAmbient is equal or higher than thermostatTemperatureSetpoint?
I tried to write
type: device.state.TemperatureSetting # For devices that support temperature points and modes.
    state: activeThermostatMode

    # Whether a device with an on/off switch is on or off. <code>true</code> if the device is on, <code>false</code> if the device is off. [available operators: is, isNot]

    is: on

    device: exampleTRBZV - exampleRoom

But device is always on=true, no matter what the position of the valve is. 

Or
: device.state.TemperatureSetting # For devices that support temperature points and modes.
  device: exampleTRBZV - exampleRoom

  state: thermostatTemperatureAmbient

  is: greater_than_or_equal_to

  value: thermostatTemperatureSetpoint

With te latter I got a syntax error.
I want to learn more about it.

Instead of device.state.TemperatureSetting, try using device.exampleTRVZB.thermostatTemperatureAmbient

It seems that I run in the next syntax error:type: device.exampleTRZVB.thermostatTempAmbient # For devices that support temperature points and modes.
is greater_than_or_equal_to device.exampleTRVZB.thermostatTempSetpoint
